# How to retrieve objects with space in key saved by "Google Cloud Storage Java API"?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After upgraded the API to "Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library" from the old "Google Cloud Storage Java API", I found the objects with spaces in key can't be retrieved now.

In the web storage browser, it seems the key used by "Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library" is like "john+smith.png". But the the key used by "Google Cloud Storage Java API" is like "john%20smith.png". I think this is why now the objects saved by "Google Cloud Storage Java API" can't be retrieved by "Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library".

I also tried use the key "john%20smith.png" to retrieve object by using "Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library", it also returns "object not found".

Is there a solution for this problem?

(Ok, I updated the Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library to latest version, with tons new dependency libs, now the problem is gone)

Comment: Have you tried using "john smith.png" from the Java Client Library?

Comment: surely, this is the normal usage.

Comment: using "john smith.png" will retrieve object with key "john+smith.png" successfully, but can't retrieve "john%20smith.png". Not tried using "john+smith.png" to retrieve object yet. I think the "+" is just for displaying, it is not really a part of the key.